# Does a server socket need to be closed when all data is sent?

Tags: c#, c++, sockets

I have written a C# socket client that sends and receives data from a server socket written in C++ (for which I don't have the source code, only the binary application).

But I have problems when receiving data because I am getting the following **SocketException**:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

This is the section of the code that receives the data of the C# client :

```
byte[] response = new byte[2048];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = netStream.Read(response, 0, response.Length) > 0)
{
    // Copy the data to a memory stream until the total of bytes have been received.
}
```

If, for example, the length of message sent by the server is 1024:

- In the first iteration *netStream.Read* reads those 1024 bytes and returns 1024 to *bytesRead*.
- In the second iteration *netStream.Read* throws the previous SocketException shown instead of returning 0 to *bytesRead*.

The same happens with any length of the message received from server socket. NetworkStream.Read always throws the same **SocketException** when there is no more bytes to read.

My question is: **Is there any error in my code or is the socked server bad implemented?**

Comment: The only way you could be getting that particular error (which is `WSAETIMEDOUT`) is if you have set a [`ReadTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readtimeout?view=net-5.0) for the socket stream. Otherwise, `Read()` would simply block the caller until new data arrived.  `Read()` will return 0 only when the peer (ie the server) closes its end of the connection. The real question is, why are you trying to read more bytes than the server is sending? You have to know how the server frames its messages, you can't just read blindly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have used `ReceiveTimeout` of `TcpClient` because `Read()` hangs forever waiting for more data once it has read the total sent by server socket.
**Answering your question**:
There is a format for a frame, something like: <header><size><payload>, however, the problem is that such server can send more than one frame in a read, but there is no way to know how many frames are going to be sent.

Comment: "*I have used `ReceiveTimeout` of `TcpClient` because `Read()` hangs forever waiting for more data once it has read the total sent by server socket*" - It is supposed to. By default. sockets operate in blocking mode, unless you put them into non-blocking mode, or specify a timeout. In this case, you are getting the error because **you are reading more bytes than you are supposed to**. Just stop doing that. "*There is a format for a frame*" - Ok, NOW we're getting somewhere. The framing tells you exactly how many bytes to expect, so read JUST that number of bytes, NO MORE, NO LESS.

Comment: "*server can send more than one frame in a read, but there is no way to know how many frames are going to be sent*" - that is perfectly fine. You don't need to know. TCP is a byte *stream*, it has no concept of messages, that is why framing is used. Read ONLY the bytes of the `<header>`, then read ONLY the bytes of the `<size>`, then read ONLY the bytes of the `<payload>`, then STOP and process the frame as needed. Then later on, read ONLY the bytes for the next `<header>`, `<size>` and `<payload>`, then STOP. Repeat as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the clarification. I thought that the right way was to read all the bytes sent by the socket and then decode those bytes according to the framing format. I thought that reading the content sent by the socket in the way you suggested it was a bad practice because it was tightly coupled to the framing format. Even I though that the server socket was bad implemented.

Comment: "*I thought that the right way was to read all the bytes sent by the socket and then decode those bytes according to the framing format*" - that is correct. And what I said earlier doesn't negate that. But how you read the bytes is up to you, as long as you process them correctly. "*I thought that reading the content sent by the socket in the way you suggested it was a bad practice because it was tightly coupled to the framing format.*" - it is coupled. But nothing prevents you from separating your reading logic from your processing logic so they are agnostic to each other.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Many thanks. I have a clearer idea now :)